# Why can't I launch this modal view from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to do something pretty easy, in my estimation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    prefs =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL IsLoggedIn = [prefs boolForKey:@"IsLoggedIn"];

    if(IsLoggedIn == NO)
    {
        //Show login controller
        LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];
        [lvc release];
    }
    else if(IsLoggedIn == YES)
    {
        //Continue doing crap
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    NSArray *tabs =  self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
    UIViewController *tbInvoice = [tabs objectAtIndex:0];
    tbInvoice.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Open-Mail.png"];
    UIViewController *tbClient = [tabs objectAtIndex:1];
    tbClient.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Breifcase.png"];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When using the debugger, I see it enter `if(IsLoggedIn == NO)` and run the `LoginViewController` code, but the view never shows.

It's driving me crazy.

I tried running the code after `[self.windoow makeKeyAndVisible]`, but it didn't change anything.

This code looks like every example I've seen.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Clif

Comment: where are you initializing your tabBarController?

Comment: And how does `LoginViewController` load its view? You're passing `nil` for the nib name, so you'd have to be overriding `loadView` to load the view programmatically for this to work. If so, are you calling `setView:` (or doing `self.view = whatever` if using dot syntax) in `loadView`?

Comment: @jlehr if you use nil for the nib name it will first try to use a nib named the same as the class. Still seems to be it would be better to specify it though

Comment: I originally had the nib name and bundle specified, so I know that's not the problem.  I changed it on a whim because of some code examples I found.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by where I'm initializing it? This snippet is from the AppDelegate and part of the default configuration for a tab based view project. (I'm pretty new to Objective-C/iPhone development...sorry if I seem dense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hpoe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997595/presentmodalviewcontroller-in-viewdidload-on-first-launch) will give you some idea.

Comment: I want to do it in the AppDelegate.

Comment: then code as, if(IsLoggedIn == NO)
    {
        //Show login controller
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tvc;
    }

Comment: Interesting approach.  I ended up going for the method you linked to just to get it done. :) I'll keep this in mind for future revisions.

Comment: I preferred @Rivera's solution on this occasion; deferring the display of the view controller makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    if(!loggedIn)
    {
        // Launch the app with login controller as the rootController
        self.window.rootViewController = loginController;

        // ...but switch to the original controller as soon as the UI is presented
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.window.rootViewController = originalRootController;

            // ...and silently present the login controller again with no noticeable changes
            [originalRootController presentViewController:loginController
                                                 animated:NO
                                               completion:NULL];
        });
    }
```