# Customize View Controller Stack on didFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am trying to present a tutorial/login/introduction view controller for my app on first launch using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIViewController *firstController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:firstController];

    if ([self shouldShowIntro]) {
        IntroViewController *introViewController = [[IntroViewController alloc] init];
        [firstController presentViewController:introViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This works fine, but there is an annoying visual effect that takes place... Before you see the `IntroViewController`, there is a split second where the `firstController` is visible.  I tried presenting the `IntroViewController` before setting the rootViewController of the window, but this (not surprisingly) results in the following warning:

`Warning: Attempt to present <IntroViewController: 0x7fd8eb3362f0> on <UIViewController: 0x7fd8eb335180> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

How can I modally present the IntroViewController without this annoying visual flash?  I want `IntroViewController` to already be showing after the launch screen disappears and be able to be dismissed modally.

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting / testing on?  Looks like you're not using storyboards, right?

Comment: I'm not using storyboards.  I'm currently testing on iOS 8.1, but want the solution to work on iOS 7 as well (or an alternate solution for iOS 7).

Comment: Can you post an example that exhibits the flicker?  Even adding a view controller that has a handful of controls on it doesn't cause any flicker for me.

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26856676/1049134

Comment: Why not bring the login/intro controller up as the root rather than trying to present it modally. When they login/finish, ask the app delegate via a method you provide to switch the root to your normal navigation tree. You can force this in storyboard by making your login the initial view controller which will make a nice smooth move from launch screen into login.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with no flicker running on iOS 8.1 on an iPhone 6 and in the simulator.  I used SDK version 8.1 and I think your SDK level is different because I got different warnings and results than you using your provided code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIViewController *firstController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    firstController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.window setRootViewController:firstController];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIViewController* modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        modalViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [firstController presentViewController: modalViewController animated: NO completion: nil];
    });

    // dismiss after a few seconds..
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [firstController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    });

    return YES;
}
```

**Update** with MMDrawerController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    MMDrawerController *drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] init];
    drawerController.centerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    drawerController.centerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    drawerController.rightDrawerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    drawerController.rightDrawerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll;
    drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll;

    [self.window setRootViewController:drawerController];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIViewController* modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        modalViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [drawerController presentViewController: modalViewController animated: NO completion: nil];
    });

    // dismiss after a few seconds..
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [drawerController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    });

    return YES;
}
```

Also, per you comment it sounds as if having the pre-loaded view is key.  Try invoking [firstController view] and [modalController view] before you present to ensure they're loaded.

Comment: This works for me with standard UIViewControllers, but when I switch out UIViewController for my subclassed controllers, I still see the flicker.  It may be related to my firstController being an MMDrawerController (https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).  I'm getting an "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" error in MMDrawerController.  I'll look into this.

Comment: Also, when using standard UIViewControllers, the dispatches don't seem to be necessary.  Ack, I think my problem is related to how I'm setting up MMDrawerController and not with how I'm trying to setup my UIViewController stack.  Oops.

Comment: Without the dispatch_async I get the unbalanced-calls message.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  However, I noticed something else.  When I use this code with simple UIViewControllers with solid background colors, it works.  When the modalViewController is a more complex controller (that likely takes longer to load), I still see the flicker.

Comment: try adding [firstController view] and  [modalController view] to preload the views before presenting.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but even with the MMDrawerController specific method, when I change modalController to something more complex than just a UIViewController with a background color, I still see the flicker.  This is still the case even if I preload with [modalViewController view], which is surprising; I thought that was an excellent suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

try moving this line below the code where you set your view controllers.

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIViewController *firstController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:firstController];

    if ([self shouldShowIntro]) {
        IntroViewController *introViewController = [[IntroViewController alloc] init];
        [firstController presentViewController:introViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES
}
```

Comment: It seems the firstController is still invisible during the presenting process

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
if ([self shouldShowIntro]) {
    IntroViewController *introViewController = [[IntroViewController alloc] init];
    [firstController presentViewController:introViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

in to the viewDidAppear function of FirstViewController rather than in the AppDelegate. That should suppress the warning and perform the operation smoothly.