# Code to send me to another view

Tags: ios, xcode, view

I have an app in which i have to at one point bring up another view strictly by code. I've seen suggestions to use this yet it simply doesn't work:

```
    secViewController *menu = [[secViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:menu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

i don't get any errors but the app just works as if these lines weren't there.

The code is running in a viewdidLoad in the viewcontroller of the first screen.
i want the code to take me to the secviewcontroller.

To provide even more context:

the first view includes a selector in which the user is to pick his country, after he does so the appropriate flag will appear in the second screen, the menu. I only wish the first screen to appear if it is the first time the user opens the app so I used this code:

```
   if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirsstLaunch"]) {

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirsstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
else{

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


    secViewController *menu = [[secViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:menu animated:YES completion:nil];

       // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirsstLaunch"];
        //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];}];
}
```

you can see the background color changes are there to test if the code is running, which it is.

This block of code is in the first view controller and it is supposed to send me to the second view if i have ever previously opened the app.

Would highly appreciate help, thank you very very much.

Comment: This needs way more information. What kind of class is this code executing in? Does the allocation of secViewController succeed? What's on the screen when this code is running? If it's a modal dialog it's possible this won't work.

Comment: Are you even sure these lines are being run? Have you been using breakpoints?

Comment: @CrimsonChris i have not been using breakpoints. I am sure that the code is being run, i used something simple instead of it (a bckgrnd color change) and it worked.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is generally an unreliable place to present modals. Try presenting from `viewDidAppear` instead

Comment: @neal I have changed the question in order to provide more detail, thank you very much for helping

Comment: @StefanGergely A few pointers. Classes should be UpperCamelCase. Breakpoints are your friend. Consider whose responsibility it is to present your "second view controller". Perhaps it is the thing which is also presenting your "first view controller".

Comment: @spassas If i place the code in viewDidAppear it shows the wrong thing for a second then blacks out, don't think it will work...

Comment: @CrimsonChris So what you are saying is I should make the menu pop up first and if the app has never been opened before make the setting screen pop up. I could do that and I have tried, I still believe the problem resided within the 2 lines of code that should send me to the other screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [presentModalViewController in viewDidLoad on first launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997595/presentmodalviewcontroller-in-viewdidload-on-first-launch)

Comment: @StefanGergely Don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`.

Comment: @CrimsonChris same issue.... is there really no other way to send the user to another screen?

Comment: @StefanGergely What exactly is the "same issue"? As far as I understand your code gets properly called when placed in `viewDidAppear`. From there on, check that you are initiating your `menu` view controller properly.

Comment: @spassas the same issue is that it doesn't bring up the other view. It bring up the same view, just purple :))) and then fades to a black screen if i use viewdidappear

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a navigation controller.

## AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MyFirstViewController alloc] init]];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {
        [navController pushViewController:[[MySecondViewController alloc] init] animated:NO];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If i use a navigation controller, is there any way I can not have the buttons on top so that my app can occupy the whole screen without what would be a sort of useless button to return to the settings page?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of UINavigationController. Pretty sure there is a way to hide the nav bar.